# Why won't my equation references work?

Tags: cross-referencing

After changing my engine to biber from bibtex to ensure my bibliography worked, it no longer recognises my cross-references to labelled equations and theorems in my script. They are labelled and referenced as follows:

```
...\label{equation}...
...\ref{equation}...
```

When I typeset in LaTeX the console reads as:

```
...LaTeX Warning: Reference 'FactCor' on Page 28 undefined on input line 748...
...Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:ï¿œ not set up for use with LaTeX
```

[image]

Comment: *A priori*, cross references have nothing to do with bibliography, so could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: All of my labels contain only letters, numbers of '.'. I'm afraid I don't know what a minimal working example is (I'm fairly beginner).

Comment: Regarding the MWE: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/44127 As pointed out already this should have nothing to do with Biber. Did you copy parts of your equation / label from somewhere like a PDF?

Comment: I don't. The errors in my console keep changing despite me not changing any of my code. The errors I am now getting are saying:
`Package asthma Warning: Unknown theoremstyle 'theorem' on input line 34`
However this worked before. Also the error:
`Package biblatex Warning: 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.`

Comment: `\usepackage{csquotes}` for the latter

Comment: I have checked the bibliography and changed the 'ö' but to no avail. Please see a picture in my edit about for the error in the console about a float h and the character error.

Comment: try putting `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` into your preamble, delete all files created during compile (aux, bbl, ...) and compile again. If I take your code from this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351775/how-to-successfully-put-a-bibliography-in-a-report-on-texshop question, that worked for me ... Does that work? Since I'm not sure how you're defining/calling your equations, I cannot test further.

Comment: Okay, that worked to stop the errors occurring, but now my bibliography has disappeared! Also, I try to run my .bib file in BibTeX it says that it can't find my corresponding .bcf file.

Comment: how do you build your file? you may need several runs of pdflatex and biber for it to build correctly ... I'm using latexmk, so I'm never sure on the correct order .. It should be pdflatex, biber, 2x pdflatex

Comment: I try this in the normal fashion but the error still occurs when trying to run my .bib file in BibTeX with the error mentioned previously.

Comment: Configuring TeXShop to run biber: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations/154778#154778
and selecting "pdflatexmk" from the dropdown menu (to the left of the typset button) works for me.

Comment: Thanks @wiebke this has finally worked and solved my problems.

Comment: Good to hear, I've as posted an answer to your other question, since the two are essentially the same, but on the other one it was much clearer what you're asking. I'd appreciate if you accept my answer :)

Comment: @CharleyScotford: Why did you delete the other question? I would like to have answered it ...